# Misconception regarding the matrix values e and f in svg

Tags: javascript, svg, matrix

I seem to have a logical misconception, regarding the [`matrix`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) of svg elements, specifically the parts **e** and **f**, which I hope someone can help me clarify.

Basing on [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/coords.html):

> Translation is equivalent to the matrix:
>
> [image]
>
> or **[1 0 0 1 tx ty]**, where *tx* and *ty* are the distances to translate
> coordinates in *x* and *y*, respectively.

### Example

Following a small example providing two `svg`. Each containing one `path` which both get rotated by `15°`. I tried to mark the point **p(x1,y1)** by a lime `circle`.

```js
;window.onload = () => {
  //REM: Query the first element in svg => [path, path]
  document.querySelectorAll('svg > *[transform]').forEach((element) => {
    let tSVG = element.ownerSVGElement;
    let tBBox = element.getBBox();
    let tMatrix = element.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).matrix;

    //REM: Draw a circle at p(x1,y1) - before rotation
    let tOldX = tBBox.x * tMatrix.a + tMatrix.e;
    let tOldY = tBBox.y * tMatrix.d + tMatrix.f

    let tCircle1 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
    tCircle1.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', '5');
    tCircle1.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'orange');
    tCircle1.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill-opacity', '0.5');
    tCircle1.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', tOldX);
    tCircle1.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', tOldY);
    tSVG.appendChild(tCircle1);

    //REM: Rotate by 15° around center of itself
    let tTransform = tSVG.createSVGTransform();
    tTransform.setRotate(15, tBBox.x + tBBox.width / 2, tBBox.y + tBBox.height / 2);
    element.transform.baseVal.appendItem(tTransform);
    element.transform.baseVal.initialize(element.transform.baseVal.consolidate());

    //REM: Fetch new matrix
    tMatrix = element.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).matrix;

    //REM: Pure scale
    let tScaleX = Math.sqrt(tMatrix.a * tMatrix.a + tMatrix.b * tMatrix.b);
    let tScaleY = Math.sqrt(tMatrix.c * tMatrix.c + tMatrix.d * tMatrix.d);

    //REM: Draw a circle at p(x1,y1) - after rotation
    let tNewX = tBBox.x * tScaleX + tMatrix.e;
    let tNewY = tBBox.y * tScaleY + tMatrix.f;

    let tCircle2 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
    tCircle2.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', '5');
    tCircle2.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'lime');
    tCircle2.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill-opacity', '0.9');
    tCircle2.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', tNewX);
    tCircle2.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', tNewY);
    tSVG.appendChild(tCircle2);

    //REM: Connection
    let tLine = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
    tLine.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', 'green');
    tLine.setAttributeNS(null, 'x1', tOldX);
    tLine.setAttributeNS(null, 'y1', tOldY);
    tLine.setAttributeNS(null, 'x2', tNewX);
    tLine.setAttributeNS(null, 'y2', tNewY);
    tSVG.appendChild(tLine);

    console.log(
      'e: ' + tMatrix.e,
      'f: ' + tMatrix.f
    )
  })
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox = '950,-250,100,400' height='800' width='300'>
  <path d = 'm1029.31 112.6h97.40v57.01h-97.40z' fill = 'red' transform = 'matrix(0.9, 0, 0, 0.9, 15, -15)' />
</svg>

<svg xmlns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox = '-40,-40,150,100' height='200' width='300'>
  <path d = 'M0 0L100 0L100 60L0 60z' fill = 'blue' transform = 'matrix(0.9, 0, 0, 0.9, 15, -15)'></path>
</svg>
```

### Question

To my understanding, I should be able to get the point **p(x1,y1)** aka **top-left**, by using the following calculation:

- **x1:** (bbox.x * scale) + matrix.e  *//original position x scaled + object moved by x*
- **y1:** (bbox.y * scale) + matrix.f  *//original position y scaled + object moved by y*

Yet, it merely works in the second/blue svg and not the first/red one. The **f** of the first/red svg seems way off to me:

- **e:** 80.92766714917656 f: -261.78134648854723 *//first/red svg*
- **e:** 23.52145237337207 f: -25.726854765665173 *//second/blue svg*

Where am I going wrong with this?

### Remark

While I added the Javascript tag for the syntax, the focus is not on Javascript. Javascript offers other possibilities to place the lime `circle` correctly.

Comment: You are missing a multiplication in both your coordinates, regarding *(b,c)*. The reason it works on both unrotated shapes is due to *(b,c)* being zero at that time and the reason it works on the blue shape is due to *x* being zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't look into why exactly it was failing. I have a couple of ideas.  But if you apply the correct matrix multiplication formulas, it works correctly.

```
let tNewX = tBBox.x * tMatrix.a + tBBox.y * tMatrix.c + tMatrix.e;
let tNewY = tBBox.x * tMatrix.b + tBBox.y * tMatrix.d + tMatrix.f;
```

```js
;window.onload = () => {
  //REM: Query the first element in svg => [path, path]
  document.querySelectorAll('svg > *[transform]').forEach((element) => {
    let tSVG = element.ownerSVGElement;
    let tBBox = element.getBBox();
    let tMatrix = element.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).matrix;

    //REM: Draw a circle at p(x1,y1) - before rotation
    let tOldX = tBBox.x * tMatrix.a + tMatrix.e;
    let tOldY = tBBox.y * tMatrix.d + tMatrix.f

    let tCircle1 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
    tCircle1.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', '5');
    tCircle1.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'orange');
    tCircle1.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill-opacity', '0.5');
    tCircle1.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', tOldX);
    tCircle1.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', tOldY);
    tSVG.appendChild(tCircle1);

    //REM: Rotate by 15° around center of itself
    let tTransform = tSVG.createSVGTransform();
    tTransform.setRotate(15, tBBox.x + tBBox.width / 2, tBBox.y + tBBox.height / 2);
    element.transform.baseVal.appendItem(tTransform);
    element.transform.baseVal.initialize(element.transform.baseVal.consolidate());

    //REM: Fetch new matrix
    tMatrix = element.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).matrix;

    //REM: Draw a circle at p(x1,y1) - after rotation
    let tNewX = tBBox.x * tMatrix.a + tBBox.y * tMatrix.c + tMatrix.e;
    let tNewY = tBBox.x * tMatrix.b + tBBox.y * tMatrix.d + tMatrix.f;

    let tCircle2 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
    tCircle2.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', '5');
    tCircle2.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'lime');
    tCircle2.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill-opacity', '0.9');
    tCircle2.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', tNewX);
    tCircle2.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', tNewY);
    tSVG.appendChild(tCircle2);

    //REM: Connection
    let tLine = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
    tLine.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', 'green');
    tLine.setAttributeNS(null, 'x1', tOldX);
    tLine.setAttributeNS(null, 'y1', tOldY);
    tLine.setAttributeNS(null, 'x2', tNewX);
    tLine.setAttributeNS(null, 'y2', tNewY);
    tSVG.appendChild(tLine);

    console.log(
      'e: ' + tMatrix.e,
      'f: ' + tMatrix.f
    )
  })
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox = '950,-250,100,400' height='800' width='300'>
  <path d = 'm1029.31 112.6h97.40v57.01h-97.40z' fill = 'red' transform = 'matrix(0.9, 0, 0, 0.9, 15, -15)' />
</svg>

<svg xmlns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox = '-40,-40,150,100' height='200' width='300'>
  <path d = 'M0 0L100 0L100 60L0 60z' fill = 'blue' transform = 'matrix(0.9, 0, 0, 0.9, 15, -15)'></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: I can confirm that it works in my example and also in the other testcases I wrote. Sadly I still do not understand why or rather what you did. Assuming you are familiar with Javascript the **BBox** provides the start of the boundingbox (x,y) without transformations on same level. The **Matrix** holds the already calculated translation (e,f). So adding the translations (e,f) to the starting position (x,y) should provide me the top-left point, should it not?

Comment: The bbox returned by `getBBox()` does not include any changes caused by transform.  So to find the coordinates of the top-left point *post* transformation, you need to take the top left point and multiply it by the transform matrix.  Which is what I did.

Comment: @Lain, The issue you might have, using your words, probably is assuming *p(x1,y1) = (x,y) + (e,f)*. The boundingbox is not a specific point and the translate moves the whole shape and not a specific point. Your formula is only correct as long as the *p(x1,y1)* defines the top-left corner of the shape or the boundingbox returns zero. However, rotating it by 15° clockwise moves that point to the right and the previous bottom-left point becomes the left edge. That is why you have to apply the transformation to the boundingbox as well, which you already partly did with the scaling.